# 'Too many requests Error' in a web scraping session

Tags: python, parsing, screen-scraping, urllib, http-status-code-429

I'm new in web scraping. I'm trying to download subtitles from https://www.opensubtitles.org with this (for now) rough function:

```
def subtitle_maker(episode_zip):
    resp=urlopen(episode_zip)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(resp.read())) as z:
        for filename in z.namelist():
                if not os.path.isdir(filename):
                    if filename.endswith('.srt'):
                        with z.open(filename) as f:
                            subtitle=f.read().decode("latin-1")
    return(subtitle)
```

I have a list of urls like this (https://dl.opensubtitles.org/it/download/sub/8861872) that I use as argument of 'subtitle_maker function' and for each url, with a 'for loop', I try to append the output of that function to the list item, but after a few cycles the program is stopped due to `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests`.
How can I manage to avoid this and pursue my goal?
Thanks

Comment: Add a delay to your script so you don't exceed the site's rate limit.

Comment: read opensubtitles API documentation, and once you know their rate limits, add time.sleep(X) when you're about to hit the limit.

https://opensubtitles.stoplight.io/docs/opensubtitles-api/6ef2e232095c7-best-practices#limits

5 requests per 1 second

Comment: @YoavSheetrit I tried it already but it doesn't work

Comment: @EnricoCaria sometimes there may additional limits (per hour, per day, etc)
It seems they return in their response headers the ratelimit-remaining (remaining requests), and the general ratelimit-limit (the limit to this api endpoint). try to work with that

Comment: I don't know how to proceed, can anyone help me?